# Findin a pattern in a string with loops in python

Tags: python, string, for-loop, pattern-matching

I'm trying to write a function that will determine whether a given pattern exists in a given string. For example "abc" in "afewtabcks"
To do this, I have written a main function that will prompt for inputs, and then call another function ("match") to determine whether the pattern entered exists in the entered string. The problem is I have no idea how to loop through a string to check for patterns without using any substring methods.

Here's what I have:

```
def main():
    string=input("String")
    pattern=input("Pattern")
    if match==True:
        print "A perfect match!"
    else match==False:
        print "Better try again..."

def match(string, pattern):
    for i in range (len(string)-len(pattern)+1):
```

Comment: This is a subset of the 'longest common substring' problem; look up algorithms for that then simplify from there.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
def match():
    string = raw_input('String')
    pattern = raw_input('Pattern')
    if pattern in string:
        print 'A perfect match!'
    else:
        print 'Better try again...'
```

The `in` operator used with strings checks for the existence of a substring inside a string.

So simple. No need for substring methods. That's why I love python!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do it without using "pattern" or "in", and I got this far, but the last part doesn't seem to work:

```
def main():
string=input("String")
pattern=input("Pattern")
m = match(string, pattern)
if m==True:
    print ("A perfect match!")
elif m==False:
    print ("Better try again...")
def match(string, pattern):
    string=str(string)
    pattern=str(pattern)
    index=0
    while index<=string:
        if string[index:len(pattern)]==pattern:
            return True
        index = index +1
    return False
```

Comment: Why would you want to re-invent the wheel and write more lines of code?
From the Zen of Python:
-Beautiful is better than ugly
-Simple is better than complex